# How to Stop msalInstance.loginRedirect redirecting to Microsoft login page MSAL.js

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a web application which initially check for office365 logged in user another tab, if logged in, application will get user the data.

If user is not logged in another tab it will redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ but it should redirect to application login page.

Is there any way to show application login page instead of Microsoft login page.

```
 let msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: client_id,
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+tenet_id,
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
            redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:3300/login',
            resource: 'https://management.azure.com/'
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };
    var msalInstance = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    var tokenRequest = {
        scopes: ["user.read"],
    }

    function login() {
        msalInstance.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => {
            if (error) console.error(error);
            console.log(response);
        })
        msalInstance.loginRedirect(tokenRequest);
    }

    msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
    .then(res => localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(res)))
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        login()
    })
```

Comment: Thanks ... your code helped me ..